# Why gradle runs all JavaExec tasks?

Tags: gradle

I defined two tasks in my `build.gradle`

```
task a(type: JavaExec) {
}

task b(type: JavaExec) {
}
```

When I execute task `a`, `b` also runs. Is this normal?

```
gradle a
```

Comment: no, it's absolutely not the expect behavior: if you did not create any dependency between tasks a & b, there is no reason that `b` is executed when running `a` task.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sharing my own experience for others.

I am a newbie on groovy/gradle.

What I tried to achieve was using a shared function for getting project properties.

```
def projectProperty = {
    if (!project.hasProperty(it)) {
        throw new Exception...
    }
    return project.getProperty(it);
}

task a(type: JavaExec) {
    do some with projectProperty(a);
}

task b(type: JavaExec) {
    do some with projectProperty(b);
}
```

And I changed like this.

```
task a(type: JavaExec) {
    if (project.hasProperty('a')) {
        do some with projectProperty('a');
    }
}

task b(type: JavaExec) {
    if (project.hasProperty('b')) {
        do some with projectProperty('b');
    }
}
```